# How to disable auto update in Wordpress manually

Tags: wordpress

Hi so i want to manually configure my `wp-config.php` file so that my wordpress never updates. But i don't see this line of code

```
define( 'WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', false );
```

I see this line of code but it is about debugging

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
```

Also how and where do i adds this

Disable automatic WordPress plugin updates:

```
add_filter( 'auto_update_plugin', '__return_false' );
```

Disable automatic WordPress theme updates:

```
add_filter( 'auto_update_theme', '__return_false' );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just add the line

```
define( 'AUTOMATIC_UPDATER_DISABLED', true );
```

to your wp-config.php after your

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
```

This should deactivate all automatic updates of your WordPress installation.

You can find more information on the auto update functionality of WordPress in their Codex Pages: [Configuring Automatic Background Updates](https://codex.wordpress.org/Configuring_Automatic_Background_Updates)

Answer (score 0):

It is simple. You can include this lines of code into your `wp-config.php`:

```
define( 'AUTOMATIC_UPDATER_DISABLED', true );
```

You can insert the lines under the define of WP_DEBUG.